# Xcode 7.2 Interface Builder fails to display different custom font styles

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, xcode7, custom-font

I have added 3 custom font (.ttf) files to my iOS app: GT Walsheim Pro Regular, Bold and Medium.

I can load the fonts programmatically just fine, and if I enumerate the names, I get 3 distinct names:

```
GTWalsheimProRegular
GTWalsheimProBold
GTWalsheimProMedium
```

However, when I try to select the font style in interface builder, I get 3 instances of "Regular" for this font family, and no matter which one I choose, I get the regular font:

[image: Interface builder fail]

How can I select the Bold or Medium font in Interface Builder ? What can I do to troubleshoot ?

Comment: have you tried to restart Xcode ?

Comment: Yes, I tried restarting Xcode :-)

Comment: have you installed them on the system ?

Comment: I just downloaded some fonts, added to the project and result was the same as yours. Installing fonts on the machine, solved the issue.

Comment: @azimov installing the font seems to be the solution. If you add that as an answer, I can accept it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install fonts on the machine and they will be listed in Xcode as expected.

Comment: Confirm this to solve loading problems (both in code and interface builder)